# How to get numbers with "." using regex

Tags: python, regex

So I have been trying to use regex (Still learning) and been trying to get the last value of this Combination

```
new avCombination('919712-041','HelloWorld','40.5');
new avCombination('919712-041','HelloWorld','41');
new avCombination('919712-041','HelloWorld','42');
new avCombination('919712-041','HelloWorld','42.5');
new avCombination('919712-041','HelloWorld','43');
new avCombination('919712-041','HelloWorld','44');
new avCombination('919712-041','HelloWorld','44.5');
new avCombination('919712-041','HelloWorld','45');
new avCombination('919712-041','HelloWorld','45.5');
```

and I have been trying to figure out using python but I have got stuck at

```
*Updated:* 
for values in re.findall('(\d+)(?=\'\);)', listOfCombinations)):
    print(values)
```

but the error I am getting is the last number of each . so meaning etc 40.5 will just return me 5 instead of 40.5

and I believe I have done my regex wrong! What should I do to solve it here?

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant, but you've got a `:` instead of `;` at the end of that second line.

Comment: Could you include a few more examples? Will the last argument always be a number?

Comment: Sure! I will add more now @rahlf23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to your attempted unpacking. Note that `re.findall()` returns a list, therefore you would want to do something along the lines of:

```
for i in re.findall(.....):
    print(i)
```

Assuming that the last argument in the JS function you are trying to parse will always be a `float`, you can do the following (where `s` is your string containing all of the JS functions):

```
list(map(float, re.findall(r'([\d\.]+)(?=\'\);)', s)))
```

Yields:

```
[40.5, 41.0, 42.0, 42.5, 43.0, 44.0, 44.5, 45.0, 45.5]
```

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for! However I did notice an issue (And it is nothing wrong but my fault) basically if a value 950209 has a value etc 1235.5 (added a .5) it will just take the last 5 right? Is it possible to take the full value of `1235.5` ?

Comment: I have now updated my question and u might be able to read it more correctly by my mistake :D

Comment: Edited my answer to account for `float` values